# Ember Data: Delete record on server but keep in store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember Data, how do I delete a record on the server but keep it in the store as a new, unsaved record?

Basically, I want something like `destroyRecord` that leaves the record in the state as if it was just created with its previous attributes. I've been looking at the state machine but can't figure out how to manually set the right states. Just creating a new record would be inconvenient since the record is being displayed in a list (via relationships) and I would like it to keep the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data has no built in way to do this, just send back a delete manually using ajax, it will be simpler than trying to hack Ember-Data to do it.

Comment: You're right. I've taken a slightly different path now, I have a component that stays there after a record has been deleted and renders the same, whether its associated record still there or whether its not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the adapter directly:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';
const { getOwner } = Ember;

export default DS.Model.extend(

......
......

deleteOnServer: function() {
    var store = getOwner(this).lookup('service:store');
    var type = this.constructor;
    var snapshot = this._createSnapshot();
    return store.adapterFor(type.modelName).deleteRecord(store, type, snapshot);
}
```

Using _createSnapshot() might break in future ember-data versions though.